# Magento remove left side panel from static block page

Tags: magento, e-commerce, magento-1.7, static-block

I created a subcategory name "NEW" from manage category option in admin.In the "Display Settings" tab  of this category, I select a CMS block which I created earlier.

This block is displaying when click on the navigation menu link "NEW".I am using one column layout.
Even so, it is showing left-side panel, which is showing to compare product option and content.

Now my question is how to remove this left-side panel from this block.I just only want content on this block. 
I am attaching snapshot of my problem
http://d.pr/i/l5bO

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your reply but I got the answer:-
go to category->add subcategory->custom design->Custom Layout Update 
paste this code.

```
<reference name="root">
 <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this on

```
<remove name="catalog.leftnav"/>
```

Here **name** is your unique `left panel name`

Also

please insert the  `**<remove name="catalog.leftnav"/>**` code inside

```
<reference name="left">
</reference>
```

like this

```
<reference name="left">
     <remove name="catalog.leftnav"/>
 </reference>
```

***It works***

Comment: I did as you tell,Compare and currency block removed from left navigation but still one line is remaining there.Like in this snapshot http://d.pr/i/aE6t I only want my content on this page from left no other things.

Comment: @NeerajGarg which one is remaining?

Comment: I am giving you all snapshots which i did.I simply create a static  block after this use this block in a category.In display Settings of category I have (http://d.pr/i/Kr5b) . In custom design I have (http://d.pr/i/bDEK) And this the snap shot at front end (http://d.pr/i/aE6t).